# Book series about opposite tribes, one hunts the other to survive

Tags: story-identification, books

What book series is about 2 tribes of people… one tribe are the hunters and have to hunt the other to survive. The other tribe honor the “sacrifices” who die to feed the other tribe. In maybe the 2nd book the main “hunter” tries to become “vegan” to stop hunting and learns that the other tribe is starting to be “farmed” for meat.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Where are these tribes, on Earth, on another planet, on a spaceship?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Novel series with ritual cannibalism and flesh essential for life](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244782/novel-series-with-ritual-cannibalism-and-flesh-essential-for-life)

Comment: Hi, is it [this book](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244782/novel-series-with-ritual-cannibalism-and-flesh-essential-for-life)? I asked this question a while back.

Comment: @bob1 nice find